# Is there a way to copy a large volume of excel data into a Microsoft SharePoint online list?

Tags: excel, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have an excel file containing 50000 records and I'm basically wanting to implement a routine job that would copy all these records and store it in a SharePoint List in SharePoint online, and on a periodic basis keep updating the list.
As a try out, I did try setting up a Microsoft Flow workflow using Power Automate and found that it can copy only till 5000 records.
Was wondering if there is any other way this could be achieved? Any help can be appreciated on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to SharePoint list view threshold is 5000, so you could only copy 5000 records in a view.

As a workaround, you should create 10 views in a list, then copy 5000 records in each view by using flow.